# using a case when to identify if a timestamp = 'null'

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to construct a case when statement in BQ on a timestamp column called version_end_ts.  Specifically I want my statement to read:

case when version_end_ts = 'null' then 'active' else 'past' end as status

Problem is BQ is is telling me that it "Could not cast literal "null" to type TIMESTAMP".   Is there a way to return a positive flag in my case when if the timestamp is missing?  I searched high and low and couldn't find an answer to this one.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Brian

[version_end_ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB3QO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact duplicate for your question, at least not for BigQuery.  In BigQuery (and most flavors of SQL), `NULL` is a special value, and checking for the presence/absence of a `NULL` value uses the special operators `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.  So your `CASE` expression should look something like this:

```
CASE WHEN version_end_ts IS NULL THEN 'active' ELSE 'past' END AS status
```

The reason for why we need to use `IS NULL` rather than `=` is that `NULL`, by definition, represents a value which is not known.  So it doesn't make sense to compare something not known with the `=` operator, because it would never be true.

Comment: Ah. Got it.  Thanks so much Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Below is yet another option (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
IF(version_end_ts IS NULL, 'active', 'past') AS status
```

It is matter of preferences - i usually prefer less verbose options

You can check above with dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT NULL AS version_end_ts UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
)
SELECT 
  version_end_ts, 
  IF(version_end_ts IS NULL, 'active', 'past') AS status
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row version_end_ts                  status   
1   null                            active   
2   2018-08-16 05:24:53.221575 UTC  past
```